# How to navigate using navigation button inside a navigation items? SwifitUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a code and I try to navigate using the NavigationButton that is inside a NavigationBarItems, however, it does not work. When trying to use the code snippet with the NavigationButton outside the NavigationBarItems the code works perfectly.

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing:
                    NavigationButton(destination: MyView()) {
                        Text("New")
                    }
```

Comment: You should probably add more code, it is hard to answer with so little information. Try to include enough so that it can be tested.

Comment: Without enough code to duplicate the issue, it's hard to help. There's been a few questions on this too - have you tried searching this site for them? (Hint: search on *[swiftui] Navigation"* and take the time to look through all of them - one might help you out.) Finally, if it "works perfectly" one way but "does not work" another way, maybe you could include more details of what you mean by each of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my (limited) understanding that a NavigationButton is primarily for use around a list item to create a segue to a detail page. I am not sure that using it inside a navigationBarItems is an appropriate or supported use case. Why not use a normal button like so?

`.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: { self.showingAddView = false } ) { Text("Done") })`